# Using package.json exports in a Typescript package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, package.json

I have a local Typescript package that I am importing into a project using `npm I ./path/to/midule`. The `package.json` for this package looks as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "my_package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./build/src/index.js",
    ...
}
```

I am trying to switch from using the `main` field to the newer `exports` field as I would like more control over how my package is imported. I tried to replace the `main` field with something I thought to be equivalent:

```json
{
    "name": "my_package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./build/src/index.js"
    },
    ...
}
```

This however, does not work. When trying to import the package into my other project, I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'my_package' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I am generating the `.d.ts` files using the `declarations` flag with the typescript compiler and specified provided the exact path to the `index.d.ts` file in `package.json`, but the same error message persisted.

I am probably missing something simple, but can't seem to find what it is. How can I use the `exports` field in a Typescript package?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the answer:
You need to set the `moduleResolution` field in your `tsconfig.json` file to `nodenext`. I also needed to update to the latest LTS version of node.js.

Comment: Too bad we need to set this option in the module client project  So we can't use it safely when publishing a npm package. Really looking for an alternative!